# when should we use executor framework in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

As per multithreading, if we wanna execute multiple tasks simultaneously in lesser time, we use it.
But never actually got the real-time project use of it?
I mean like where exactly can we use this executor framework, where we create a pool of threads and they will perform a specific task.
What can be the applications for this and why prefer it over a normal threading implementation using runnable?

Comment: I you are using a Java EE server, you must use an injected ManagedExecutorService to launch a task

Answer (score 0):

The concurrent API supplies a feature named an executor, in addition, the concurrent API defines three predefined executor classes: ThreadPoolExecutor,
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, and ForkJoinPool

A pool thread provides a set of threads that are used to execute various tasks, instead of each task using its own thread,

The Executor framework used in web e-commerce applications as well as other types of applications,

the below program illustrates the use of the Executor framework:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
class SimpExec {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(5);
  CountDownLatch cdl2 = new CountDownLatch(5);
  CountDownLatch cdl3 = new CountDownLatch(5);
  CountDownLatch cdl4 = new CountDownLatch(5);
  ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  System.out.println("Starting");
  // Start the threads.
  es.execute(new MyThread(cdl, "A"));
  es.execute(new MyThread(cdl2, "B"));
  es.execute(new MyThread(cdl3, "C"));
  es.execute(new MyThread(cdl4, "D"));
  try {
  cdl.await();
  cdl2.await();
  cdl3.await();
  cdl4.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
    System.out.println(exc);
  }
   es.shutdown();
  System.out.println("Done");
  }
  }


 class MyThread implements Runnable {
 String name;
 CountDownLatch latch;
 MyThread(CountDownLatch c, String n) {
 latch = c;
 name = n;
 new Thread(this);
 }
 public void run() {
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 System.out.println(name + ": " + i);
latch.countDown();
}
}
}
```

output :
Starting
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2
A: 3
A: 4
C: 0
C: 1
C: 2
C: 3
C: 4
D: 0
D: 1
D: 2
D: 3
D: 4
B: 0
B: 1
B: 2
B: 3
B: 4
Done

for further reading, I would suggest reading Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz

Answer (score 0):

There are number of scenarios where you can leverage the `executor framework` such as sending the mails or transfer of files etc asynchronously.

> why prefer it over a normal threading implementation using runnable?

Firstly, the major benefit of using the thread pool is that it reduces the response time by avoiding thread creation during request or task processing. Secondly, executor framework handle the thread management, so you don't need to take care of it.